# How do I get predict to output a label rather than a probability?

Tags: r

I am expecting to see labels output here but I see probabilities
Why?

```
train <- read.csv("ClassTrain.csv")
glm.fit <- glm(Salary ~ .,data=train,family=binomial)
predict.label <- predict(glm.fit,train, type = 'response')
head(predict.label)
```

The labels in the Salary column are True and False

I recall the code used to work.
I have since upgraded to be running R version 3.6.1

[image: Output]

Comment: The current R version is 4.0.5

Comment: `predict.label>0.5` should work

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with, including a sample of data so we can run your code

Comment: @DeanMacGregor that is the answer. Care to write it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the probability response into a boolean with `predict.label>0.5`